# How does the inherits function work in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, node.js

This is the inherits function in node.js:

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable:    false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

Can somebody please give me the "big picture" of how this function works?
I am not 100% sure I get Object.create , and... well I am confused!

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated...

Merc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Parent = function () {
  this.isParent = true;
};

Parent.prototype.doSomething = function () {
  return 42;
};

var Child = function () {
  this.isChild = true;
}
util.inherits(Child, Parent);

var c = new Child;
console.log(c.isChild);
console.log(c.doSomething());
```

It simply makes sure that `Child.prototype` inherits from `Parent.prototype` properly. It also set's the `constructor` property `Child.prototype` to the correct value.

Make sure to call `util.inherits` directly after your `Child` declaration.

Comment: Not sure it's worth much, but... well, thank you. I am re-reading my question -- and the answer -- a little while later, when I finally "get" all this, and I have to say, it all looks so incredibly simple now... I guess it's time for me to go off and help others here!

Answer (score -1):

There are now two versions of inherits function. Pre node.js version 5.0.0 uses Object.create and post (inclusive) v5.0.0 uses Object.setPrototypeOf.

In Object.create version, the prototype of superCtor is set as prototype of ctor.prototype. However, in this process any methods / properties available on ctor.prototype are removed. Here is an working example;

```js
var inherits = function (ctor, superCtor) {
    ctor.super_ = superCtor;
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: ctor,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
};

function Manager(managerName) {
    this.managerName = managerName;
}

Manager.prototype.getManagerName = function () {
    return this.managerName;
}

function Team(managerName, teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    Team.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}


Team.prototype.getTeamDetails = function () {
    return this.teamName + ' is managed by ' + this.managerName;
}

inherits(Team, Manager);

var obj = new Team('Klopp', 'LiverpoolFC');

console.log(obj.getTeamDetails()); //obj.getTeamDetails is not a function
```

Above issue is solved in Node.js version 5.0.0 or later. util.inherits now uses setPrototypeOf, which addresses this issue.

```js
var inherits = function (ctor, superCtor) {
    ctor.super_ = superCtor;
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: ctor,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
};

function Manager(managerName) {
    this.managerName = managerName;
}

Manager.prototype.getManagerName = function () {
    return this.managerName;
}

function Team(managerName, teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    Team.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}


Team.prototype.getTeamDetails = function () {
    return this.teamName + ' is managed by ' + this.managerName;
}

inherits(Team, Manager);

var obj = new Team('Klopp', 'LiverpoolFC');

console.log(obj.getTeamDetails()); //obj.getTeamDetails is not a function
```

This link provides detailed explanation of how inherits works in Node.js 
[Node.js - Anatomy of inherits](https://www.echosteg.com/nodejs-util-inherits-how-inheritance-works)